# Usual conditions - filtration

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ - probability space. What is the definition of filtration whch satisfy usual conditions? I know that it must be right-continuous and $\mathcal{N}\subset \mathcal{F_0}$, but what is the form of $\mathcal{N}$? Is it $\mathcal{N}=\{X\subset \Omega:X\subset Y\in\mathcal{F}, P(Y)=0\}$ or $\mathcal{N}=\{A\in \mathcal{F}:P(A)=0\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq0}, P)$ is said to satisfy the *usual conditions* if $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq0}$ is right-continuous and $\mathcal{N}\subset \mathcal{F}_0$ with $\mathcal{N}=\{X\subset \Omega|\exists Y\in\mathcal{F}: X\subset Y  \land P(Y)=0\}$.